# Laravel lcobucci JWT token issuing a token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am trying to use this package to in order to make jwt token in custom format.

But i can not understand
`$config = $container->get(Configuration::class);`

From where this $container variable is coming?

Anyone can help me?
Here is the [docs link](https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.4/issuing-tokens/)

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;

$config = $container->get(Configuration::class);
assert($config instanceof Configuration);

$now   = new DateTimeImmutable();
$token = $config->builder()
                // Configures the issuer (iss claim)
                ->issuedBy('http://example.com')
                // Configures the audience (aud claim)
                ->permittedFor('http://example.org')
                // Configures the id (jti claim)
                ->identifiedBy('4f1g23a12aa')
                // Configures the time that the token was issue (iat claim)
                ->issuedAt($now)
                // Configures the time that the token can be used (nbf claim)
                ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter($now->modify('+1 minute'))
                // Configures the expiration time of the token (exp claim)
                ->expiresAt($now->modify('+1 hour'))
                // Configures a new claim, called "uid"
                ->withClaim('uid', 1)
                // Configures a new header, called "foo"
                ->withHeader('foo', 'bar')
                // Builds a new token
                ->getToken($config->signer(), $config->signingKey());
Once you've created a token, you're able to retrieve its data and convert it to its string representation:

use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;

$config = $container->get(Configuration::class);
assert($config instanceof Configuration);

$token = $config->builder()
                ->issuedBy('http://example.com')
                ->withClaim('uid', 1)
                ->withHeader('foo', 'bar')
                ->getToken($config->signer(), $config->signingKey());

$token->headers(); // Retrieves the token headers
$token->claims(); // Retrieves the token claims

echo $token->headers()->get('foo'); // will print "bar"
echo $token->claims()->get('iss'); // will print "http://example.com"
echo $token->claims()->get('uid'); // will print "1"

echo $token->toString(); // The string representation of the object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like a call to [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#resolving)

In Laravel, you can make Configuration::class with app() helper, but more nice way - inject in from constructor

by helper

```
$config = app()->make(Configuration::class);
```

by constructor injection

```
class JWTBuilderClass
{
    private Configuration $configuration;

    public function __construct(Configuration $configuration)
    {
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }
}
```

Before you can get Configuration from container - you must put it into container - bind class. Here is [docs](https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.4/configuration/) about config creation. In AppServiceProvider::register():

```
$this->app->bind(Configuration::class, function(){
    return Configuration::forAsymmetricSigner(
    // You may use RSA or ECDSA and all their variations (256, 384, and 512) and EdDSA over Curve25519
    new Signer\Rsa\Sha256(),
    LocalFileReference::file(__DIR__ . '/my-private-key.pem'),
       InMemory::base64Encoded('mBC5v1sOKVvbdEitdSBenu59nfNfhwkedkJVNabosTw=')
    // You may also override the JOSE encoder/decoder if needed by providing extra arguments here
    );
});
```

Btw, use package [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) - it's JWT implementation for Laravel

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still i can not use this solution after using `$config = app()->make(Configuration::class);`  . i am getting following error  ` Target [Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration] is not instantiable.`